# JSON to GSON and POJO class

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, pojo

I have a JSON response like the following:

{
"number":"123456789101112",
"dimensions":"{\"height\":\"8.200\",\"width\":\"18.800\",\"depth\":\"9.400\"}",
"uom":"centimetre"
}

I am using the following to convert from JSON to GSON

Gson gson = new Gson();
 Details details = gson.fromJson(JSONresponse, Details .class);

I want to know how to map the JSON response into my pojo class for converting this JSON to GSON and retrieving individual values.

I want to know how to access the height,width,depth from the response. This is my current Details class:

public class Details

{

```
private String number;

private String dimensions;

private String uom;

public void setNumber(String number){
    this.number = number;
}
public String getNumber(){
    return this.number;
}
public void setDimensions(String dimensions){
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
}
public String getDimensions(){
    return this.dimensions;
}
public void setUom(String uom){
    this.uom = uom;
}
public String getUom(){
    return this.uom;
}
```

}

Comment: What does your `Details` class look like, and what is wrong with your current Gson code?

Comment: I want to know how to access the height,width,depth from the response. This is my current Details class:(check updated question)

Answer (score 1):

I would model your POJO as:

```
public class Details {
    private Integer number;
    private Dimension dimensions;  // lowercase according to Java naming conventions
    private String uom;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Dimension {
    private String height;
    private String width;
    private String depth;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then just use your current (correct) code, and then access whichever fields you want:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Details details = gson.fromJson(JSONresponse, Details.class);
String height = details.getDimensions().getHeight();
```

Comment: I am getting an exception if i try this way.-> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 54 path $.Dimensions] with root cause

Comment: @JESSIE If you read my answer closely, you will see that I have lowercased `dimensions`, to try to stick to Java naming conventions.  Use `Dimensions` if you must stick with your current JSON definition.

Comment: dimensions is what i get from Response. sry that was a typo. I have done the same way as u have suggested. yet the error occurs. Pls help.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that your height, width, and depth fields are actually text, so the POJO should make these fields as strings.